# Complex Number Division class

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I'm trying to overload the operator to divide two complex numbers

Testing with 3+2i / 4 - 3i

```
    complex g(3, 2);
    complex f(4,-3);

    cout << g / f << endl;
```

I added `* -1.0` since we go 
(4*4) + (3 * -3)i^2 in math which is 25

((3*4) + (3 * -3)* -1) is my intent

Testing I get `-0.545455 - 1.72727i`

While before I added the * 1.0 I got

```
0.24 +0.76i
```

Which is was very close to

```
0.24 + 0.68i
```

the answer

```
complex complex :: operator/ (complex& x) {
    complex conjugate = x.conj();
    double j = (real * conjugate.real) + (imag * conjugate.imag); // real
    double u = (real * conjugate.imag) + (imag * conjugate.real); // imag
    double h = (((conjugate.imag * imag)* -1.0) + (real * conjugate.real)) + ( (real*conjugate.imag) + (imag * conjugate.real));


    return complex(j/h,u/h);
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
double j = (real * conjugate.real) + (imag * conjugate.imag); // real
```

should be `-`, not `+`.

This is right:

```
double u = (real * conjugate.imag) + (imag * conjugate.real); // imag
```

Although both `j` and `u` are meaninglessly named.

What's going on here?

```
double h = (((conjugate.imag * imag)* -1.0) + (real * conjugate.real)) + ( (real*conjugate.imag) + (imag * conjugate.real));
```

The denominator is just `x*conjugate` which is:

```
double denom = x.real * x.real  + x.imag * x.imag;
```

---

Side-note, you want to take your argument by reference to const.

Comment: Damn, the answer still isn't 0.24 and 0.68

Comment: @GustX Flipped two signs.